# How to turn an example twitter post into it's HTML equivalent

Tags: python, html

For example, I have the string:

```
"<p class='foo'>Hello World</p>"
```

The result would then have to be:

```
"&lt;p class='foo'&gt;Hello World&lt;/p&gt;"
```

And if there were a link in the text, that would have to be converted to a HTML `<a>` tag.

In addition, if there were a mention, such as below:

```
"<p>Hello World @Mark</p>"
```

The result would be

```
"&lt;p&gt;Hello World <a href='/users/Mark'>@Mark</a>&lt;/p&gt;"
```

Note: this is in python. Is regex a possible solution?

Comment: Why does `<p` becomes  `&lt;p` but `<a` doesn't become `&lt;a`?

Comment: use beautiful soup, previous similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857627/python-beautifulsoup-parsing-out-a-tweet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`cgi.escape`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape) function to escape your string first:

```
import cgi
a = '"<p>Hello World @Mark</p>"'
escaped = cgi.escape(a)

# result will be: '&lt;p&gt;Hello World @Mark&lt;/p&gt;'
```

Then you can use regexp to replace the @Mark:

```
import re
result = re.sub('(@([-._a-zA-Z0-9]+))', r'<a href="/users/\2">\1</a>', a)

# result will be: '&lt;p&gt;Hello World <a href="/users/Mark">@Mark</a>&lt;/p&gt;'
```

If you need `<a href="...">...</a>` to be escaped as well, just run regex first.

Comment: Hi Pavel, could you explain how r'<a href="/users/\2">\1</a>' works? What are /2 and /1 in this situation?

Comment: Please look at docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub

\1, \2, etc — this are references to regex groups

Comment: Here is a quote from python regex documentation: "(...) Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, and indicates the start and end of a group; the contents of a group can be retrieved after a match has been performed, and can be matched later in the string with the \number special sequence, described below. To match the literals '(' or ')', use \( or \), or enclose them inside a character class: [(] [)]."

Comment: In my regex there are 2 groups: 1: (@...) and 2: ([-_...])

Comment: Thanks, Pavel. This gives me a good idea of what I need to do. I am getting an error though. In a situation where I have '.' in the name (e.g. @mark.knopfler) then it's causing a problem. I added in '.' into the code already, however it's causing a problem where it recognises the '.' even when the mention is just at the end of a sentence. E.g. "Hi there @mark."

Comment: I have updated the answer and it allows to have dot in name.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the mention with the @ sign, you could either regex as you mentioned, or just manually loop through each character of the string storing the staring position of the @ sign, and when you run into a character that isn't an alphanumeric character (eg. a space or an html tag/entity), then you would know you'e at the end of the mention, so you store the end. Use something like string a substring function to cut out the rest of the characters.

The rest of your code has HTML entities, just revert or remove those when ready to output.